# This application will not be accessible on iOS unless SSO is configured

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, facebook-authorization

I've received the following restriction on a mobile web app which doesn't make any sense as SSO only applies to native apps..

"This application will not be accessible on iOS unless SSO is configured"

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure SSO for your native app using the Instructions for SSO in section 3 of [the iOS SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) - once you've done that the app will be accessible as normal.

If the app doesn't have a native iOS version, your app is probably restricted from being accessed from inside Facebook's native app due to not complying with Apple's policies about iOS-approved payment methods.

You'd need to take it up with your lawyers or Facebook's policy team if that's the case - all i can answer here is the info on how to enable SSO for your native app if applicable